# Django - cycle relations between models

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

I have two models Set and Photo:

```
class Set(models.Model):
    ...
    thumbnail = models.OneToOneField('Photo')
    ...

class Photo(models.Model):
    ...
    set = models.ForeignKey('Set', related_name='photos')
    ...
```

The problem is that django can't process this code, because rendering model `Set` requires model `Photo`, which is depends from model `Set`, which is not available yet at this moment. What are the solutions of this problem?

**UPD:** Another way, but I think thats not good solution too.

```
class Set(models.Model):
    ...
    photos = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', related_name='set')
    thumbnail = models.OneToOneField('Photo')
    ...

class Photo(models.Model):
    ...
    # some fields like name, size, etc..
    ...
```

Comment: I don't believe you need that set field... what are you trying to do?

Comment: I assume he wants "sets" (collections, albums...) of photos, where one of the photos is used as a "thumbnail" (cover image, whatever) for the set. Looks pretty standard for a photo gallery or like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is somehow broken anyway as it doesn't inforce the fact that the thumbnail for a given set should be part of the set's photos. Another solution is to flag one of the set's photos as the thumbnail:

```
class Set(models.Model):
    @property
    def thumbnail(self):
        try:
            return self.photos.get(is_thumbnail=True)
        except Photo.DoesNotExist:
            # You can either use the first photo or just return None.
            # Note that if the set has no photos self.photos.first()
            # will actually return None anyway
            return self.photos.first()


class Photo(models.Model):
    set = models.ForeignKey(Set, related_name='photos')
    is_thumbnail = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # cf  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects
    def clean(self):
        if self.is_thumbnail:
           qs = self.set.photos.filter(is_thumbnail=True)
           if self.pk:
               qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.pk)
           if qs.exists():
               raise ValidationError("Only one thumbnail per set")
```

Comment: There will be no error, if I'll try to add two objects to one set and is_thumbnail will be False?

Comment: @VitalyNevgen oops my bad... Yes, you're right, of course <g>. I should know better, already had this use case quite a few times. And of course the solution is to manually enforce the constraint in the model's validation.